# How do I get the current Cosmos RUs with the .NET SDK?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When you're replacing the current RUs (say as part of autoscaling), it might be a good idea just to check what the current offer is, to avoid unnecessary calls to scale.

You can get the current offer like so.

```
var collectionOffer = _documentClient.CreateOfferQuery().Where(x => x.ResourceLink == collection.Resource.SelfLink).AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault();
```

Annoyingly, in the content for the `Offer` object, you can see the current RUs in `Content` then `offerThroughput`.

How do you get at the int without doing something hacky like converting it to JSON and back to dynamic so you can access the number?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `Offer` object inherits from `Resource`, it has a method of `GetPropertyValue<T>`. Also even more helpfully, there already is an object that basically matches the Content of the object called `OfferContentV2`.

So you can do

```
var offerContent = collectionOffer?.GetPropertyValue<OfferContentV2>("content");
```

Then the current value is `offerContent.OfferThroughput`